# Vue.js scope issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scope

Hey so im trying to use a for loop with a condition if statement to remove a class that may or may not exist on each node.

Problem is that for some reason i keep getting an error saying item[i] is undefined.
I cant figure out why I is not within the scope and is throwing undefined within the If statement. If i console Log item[i] first line after the for loop, item[i] is perfect.

Any and all help is appreciated!

```
    activeButton() {
      const item = event.target.parentNode.childNodes;
      for (let i = 0; i <= item.length; i++) {
        if (item[i].classList.contains('active')) {
          item[i].classList.remove('active');
        }
      }
      event.target.classList.toggle('active');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be passing the event into the function otherwise it won't know what `event` is (where is `event` being defined if it's not being passed in as a parameter?)

```
activeButton(event) { // added event here
    const item = event.target.parentNode.childNodes;
    for (let i = 0; i <= item.length; i++) {
        if (item[i].classList.contains('active')) {
            item[i].classList.remove('active');
        }
    }

    event.target.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

Comment: I was under the impression that the even parameter is always passed on click event without the need to be specified as being a parameter. The code works without event be specified.

Comment: @CiaranOriordan what line is the console saying `item[i]` isn't defined? I have only used Vue a little bit but in their docs they suggest the event param is necessary: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers

Answer (score 0):

Without context but I guess your loop iterate an extra time. `item[length]` would return `undefined`

```
activeButton() {
  const item = event.target.parentNode.childNodes;
  for (let i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
    if (item[i].classList.contains('active')) {
      item[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
  }
  event.target.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

Comment: @CiaranOriordan make sure to mark their Answer as the right solution if that worked for ya

Comment: @CiaranOriordan haha i don't think you meant to mark my answer as the solution